# What's the easiest way to map the universe?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

I want to deploy a satellite network through the universe, but to do that I first need to discover all the sectors. Is there an easy way to do that? I would like to avoid having to visit every sector personally or remotely ordering a ship to fly through every gate there is. Ideally, I would like to map the sectors as well.

Comment: First, get a very large piece of paper...

Comment: nope guess I was wrong, deploy satellite network doesn't go through gates

Answer (score 2):

The method I personally use is to go to a busy sector like Seizewell with a shipyard and buy 10 cheap M5 scouts. Equip each scout with a scanner. Simply tell each ship to follow one of the many NPC freighters in the sector, and try to follow a variety of different races, as they will all have very different destinations. Your scouts will slowly fill out your universe map, though they will die when the NPC freighters pass through Xenon sectors. Also, they will not create a complete map, as NPC traders do not often go to the far-reaches of the universe and unknown sectors. The rest of the exploration can be done manually.

Comment: that's a rather good idea!

Answer (score 1):

If you equip a ship with one of the special command or high level navigation software.

You can issue a command to it to explore, this will cause it to fly through gates till it runs out of sectors or most likely is destroyed.

Then you can set another ship to deploy your network.

Comment: I don't believe there is such a command - http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?p=2647826 Can you specify exactly what software needs to be installed?

Answer (score 1):

In Albion Prelude there is **Recon Bot** and **Explorer Command Software** for ships. They both have command "Fly through gate".

Both of them have command "Map sector", but you need to order it for every sector.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably to use the [Universal Explorer](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=306176&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0) mod.

Here are the key points which can interest you:

> - Player owned M3, M4, M5, and Goner Rangers (and Truelight Seeker in ship mod) may hire a pilot by choosing "Start Universe Explorer..." from the navigation commands. The ship must be equipped with Explorer Command Software.
> - If an explorer enters a sector marked as 'Foe' in their ships friend/foe settings they will retreat and try to find a different unknown sector. I always put pirates as Foe so they survive. Razz
> - As the pilot gains experience they will learn methods to increase the speed of exploring a sector. As with the original Explore Sector command the speed of the scan is very dependent on the installed scanners and speed of the ship.
> - With experience comes more methods of finding unexplored sectors, everything from random known gate wandering to using the players satellite network to communicating with other ships to get directions can eventually be used.
> - **Explorers will automatically begin to build up the players satellite network**, if one is not in place already. They will also maintain the players satellite network when they notice missing satellites. This feature and the type(s) of satellites used can be toggled in the community menu.

From what I read on the forum discussion, there are issues with it still (some ships might not work with it, for example), and it's not really supported anymore by the maintainer. But you could probably give it a try, see how it goes for you.

Comment: the problem with most mods is that it makes your game \*modified* so you can't earn cheevos.

Answer (score 0):

There's an Unidentified Object that you can sometimes find flying around.  It's very fast, but if you tell an equally fast ship to follow it, it'll fly everywhere in the universe for you eventually.

This may not be a very efficient way of achieving your goal, but it is a fun way.